# How to create a list with objects in python

Tags: python, list

```
list_name = "a"
list_element = "b"
```

I want to create a list in below format

```
a = ["b"]
```

How cani achieve this with format of `list_name` and `list_element`?

Thank you!

Comment: its never a good idea to try and create variable names dynamically like that. you should consider revising your data structure and what you want to achieve

Comment: `[list_element]`?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead:  `lists = {}; lists[list_name] = list_element`.

Comment: bad idea but any way you can: `globals()[list_name] = [list_element]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using `globals()`:

```
globals()[list_name] = [list_element]
```

out put:

```
In [1]: list_name = "a" 
In [2]: list_element = "b" 

In [3]: globals()[list_name] = [list_element]                                                                                                                                                                      

In [4]: a                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[4]: ['b']
```

Read more about [globals()](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/globals/#:~:targetText=The%20globals()%20function%20returns,from%20where%20it%20is%20called.).

Comment: Can be done but should be discouraged, normally there is a better data structure to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is to create variable names dynamically. Except if you really really need to do it, it is not recommended and can usually be avoided.

In Python, dictionaries can be used to solve this problem. A dictionary contains variables which can be called using "keys".

```
dict = {'a1' : "b1",
        'a2' : "b2"}
```

The variable (here the string "b1") associated with the key 'a1' can be called using:

```
dict['a1']
```